# Ruby on Rails require CSS error

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a problem with Ruby on Rails rquire statements.

I want to add a `reset.css` file before the `require_tree`.

I have a `application.css`:

```
/*
 *= require reset
 *= require_tree
 *= require_self .
 */
```

By doing this I am always gearing an error: `wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)`. Where is the problem?

Comment: You should pass a path as an argument for `require_tree`

Comment: The problem is with `require reset`. When I remove it, everything works just fine...

Comment: It seems you have some error in your reset.css file. Can you show its content?

Comment: It is a first one from here: http://cssreset.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`require_self` should be without `.` argument. [Here](https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets#the-require_self-directive) is specification of this directive. As you can see it doesn't have parameters.

Comment: Still doesn't work. `require_self .` is a rails generated statement.

Comment: No, Rails generate application.cs where `require_self` without dot.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets/blob/1566cd10486b677d52d93c74f489ad7a8d2acd79/test/fixtures/asset/require_self.css) is example from Sprockets tests.